# Double-Spacing an ACM Proceedings Article in LaTeX

Tags: latex, templates, tex, spacing

I am using the [acm LaTeX template](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls) and I have trouble making my paper double spaced.

My LaTeX document looks like the following:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

When I compile the above document using pdflatex, I get the following error message on the line that I use the command `\doublespacing`:

```
Missing number, treated as zero \doublespacing
```

Comment: Title should probably be changed to "Double-Spacing an ACM Proceedings Article in LaTeX" since it doesn't apply generally to LaTeX

Comment: You might need to double space it to make it easier for your peers to review and leave notes on your paper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want to use `\usepackage{doublespace}` to double-space your document.  To put in a block of singlespacing, surround it with `\begin{singlespace}` and `\end{singlespace}`.

Ref: http://web.mit.edu/olh/Latex/ess-latex.html

Comment: TeX-FAQ advises against using `doublespace`. They say to use `setspace` instead.

Answer (score 22):

`\linespread{2}` should work. Doesn't need any packages, as far as I can tell, and you could change it to 1.9-spacing or 2.1-spacing, if you felt like it...

Comment: I have used `\linespread` to great effect in the past with an argument similar to 1.2 or 1.3; I find this helps enormously when inlining vertically-aligned vectors etc.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like the `acm_proc_article-sp` class does some funky things that confuses the `setspace` package.  In the preamble of your `.tex` document, add the following lines:

```
% Redefines \@ptsize to make setspace happy
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@ptsize}{0}
\makeatother

% Double-spaces the entire document
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

I have no idea why the `acm_proc_article-sp` class redefines `\@ptsize` to be empty.

Answer (score 4):

The `acm_proc_article-sp` class seems to redefine `\@ptsize` to be empty for some reason. I don't know what `\@ptsize` is used for, so I don't want to mess with it. Using the `\show` command (see [link text](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=ltxcmds) for more on this fantastic command), I see that `\doublespacing` is unpacked into

```
\setstretch{1.667} \ifcase \@ptsize \relax \setstretch{1.667} \or 
\setstretch{1.618} \or \setstretch{1.655}\fi
```

In other words, `\doublespacing` is essentially equivalent to `\setstretch{1.667}`, with slightly different stretch factors if `\@ptsize` happens to be `1` or `2`. So I think the most unobtrusive solution to your problem is replace `\doublespacing` by `\setstretch{1.667}`.

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.667}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\@ptsize` is used in the LaTeX base classes to determine the normal font size.  When you specify `10pt`, `11pt`, or `12pt` as a document class option (e.g., `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`, then `\@ptsize` it set to the last digit (i.e., 0, 1, or 2 for 10pt, 11pt, or 12pt, respectively).  So the various line spacings in the case statement are set depending on the base font size.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried out this command (in my preamble) for double spacing and it worked fine:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to the accepted solution: you can use `\usepackage{setspace}` if you include the line `\doublespacing` within your actual document (I have it right after the `\maketitle` command), instead of in your preamble. So something like:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
...
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure why this is different, but I think including it in the actual document automagically fills in the params you're missing.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is an old thread, for those who stumble uppon:

What you have is actually correct and works. The problem is with the template that is being used. Probably it is overriding some command (like the \doublespacing).

This compiles and works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
testing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't do it. You need to follow the ACM conference proceedings article submission instructions, which don't want you to double-space the article anyway.

Comment: Maybe the author wants to temporarily use double spacing so that others can edit or comment on it more easily.

Comment: Eh … If it's for manual editing why bother with ACM styling at all?